# Optimizing volatile variables

Tags: c++, optimization, volatile

My understanding is that the C++ standard mandates that accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.  I am sure that means that the number of loads and stores to a given volatile variable cannot be changed, nor can those accesses be reordered.

But what about reordering with respect to other non-volatile access?

Can a fully redundant volatile access in both arms of an if statement be hoisted or sunk out of that if?  E.g. Assuming no data dependencies would be violated can

```
if (e) {
    = non-volatile-load;
    non-volatile-store =;
    t = volatile-load;
    = non-volatile-load;
    non-volatile-store =;
} else {
    = non-volatile-load;
    non-volatile-store =;
    t = volatile-load;
    = non-volatile-load;
    non-volatile-store =;
}
```

be optimized to

```
t = volatile-load;
if (e) {
    = non-volatile-load;
    non-volatile-store =;
    = non-volatile-load;
    non-volatile-store =;
} else {
    = non-volatile-load;
    non-volatile-store =;
    = non-volatile-load;
    non-volatile-store =;
}
```

or to

```
if (e) {
    = non-volatile-load;
    non-volatile-store =;
    = non-volatile-load;
    non-volatile-store =;
} else {
    = non-volatile-load;
    non-volatile-store =;
    = non-volatile-load;
    non-volatile-store =;
}
t = volatile-load;
```

What if the volatile-load were instead a volatile-store?

Comment: A non-volatile variable could be held in a register for its entire lifetime, and never be stored in memory.

Comment: If these "non-volatile" things (and also that "t") do not cause any side effects in undisclosed parts of code then by as-is rule the program can be optimized into just "volatile-load". If these cause then it matters what these cause.

Comment: `volatile` is not the tool to reason about load-store ordering. You need `atomic`, `mutex` or some other way to achieve acquire/release semantics.

Comment: @rustyx i think, you are confused. load/store is a quite generic term, and by no means is confined to thread synchronization domain.

Comment: Consider the case where a `volatile` variable represents a hardware register or a shared memory location (among threads).  Do your cases still hold?

Comment: Also consider timing.  Accessing `volatile` variables at different points in the code could yield different results (such as reading from an Analog To Digital converter register).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the [as-if rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#1),...

> ... conforming implementations ... are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below

And [observable behavior](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#6) is specified below as (emphasis mine)...

> – Accesses through `volatile` glvalues are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.

So yes, the compiler may reorder accesses to non-volatile variables (of course within the boundaries of memory fences in a threaded environment; `volatile` offers no such semantics, `atomic` does).

Comment: Understanding the interaction of observable behavior and the as-if rule was exactly the nudge I needed.  Thanks.

Comment: @PasserBy: Quite the contrary.  Given sufficient understanding of the non-volatile accesses both optimizations are legal.